# The Javascript Image Slider is not working well inside Chrome. Images stack up. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my client's website, (http://slnyaadev45.herokuapp.com/),I have used a JS slider on the top. It will contiguously move the images across the site. In Firefox, it works perfectly. But in Google Chrome, it doesn't. Sometimes it work but if I reload the page it stops working. Sometimes, it start to work. Then if I just click a link to another page, it will still work. But if I reload, it breaks again. The problem is also there in the Android's default browser. What is going wrong? How to fix it?

PS : The site is built with Rails 3.2.

The javascript :

```
$(function(){
    var scroller = $('#scroller div.innerScrollArea');
    var scrollerContent = scroller.children('ul');
    scrollerContent.children().clone().appendTo(scrollerContent);
    var curX = 0;
    scrollerContent.children().each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('left', curX);
    curX += $this.width();
    });
    var fullW = curX / 2;
    var viewportW = scroller.width();

    // Scrolling speed management
    var controller = {curSpeed:0, fullSpeed:1};
    var $controller = $(controller);
    var tweenToNewSpeed = function(newSpeed, duration)
    {
    if (duration === undefined)
        duration = 600;
    $controller.stop(true).animate({curSpeed:newSpeed}, duration);
    };

    // Pause on hover
    scroller.hover(function(){
    tweenToNewSpeed(0);
    }, function(){
    tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
    });

    // Scrolling management; start the automatical scrolling
    var doScroll = function()
    {
    var curX = scroller.scrollLeft();
    var newX = curX + controller.curSpeed;
    if (newX > fullW*2 - viewportW)
        newX -= fullW;
    scroller.scrollLeft(newX);
    };
    setInterval(doScroll, 20);
    tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all my images have the same size, I added the width in this line of the script :

```
curX += $this.width();
```

as :

```
curX += 224;
```

Answer (score 0):

because the distance between the elements is 4px, set the ''left'' of each element is equal to previous elements widths sum

OR

you can remove `position:absolute` for style of `li`, and add `float:left`

Comment: If I add float:left, it will freeze the animation. It won't slide!

Comment: what about set left position??

Comment: I just checked... The javascript calculate and set the left value. In Firefox, it work, but in Chrome, the "left" values are messed up!

Comment: I have just added the JS :)

Comment: $this.css('left', curX+'px'); //Write as

Comment: If I set +'px', it will work when reloeaded but on a normal visit and a link click, it stops working!